# CORS issue when combining AngularJS with PassportJS

Tags: angularjs, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to combine ExpressJS + PassportJS with Angular SPA application. The problem probably is in CORS headers.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

**Client View**:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter" ng-click="twitter()">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Sign in with Twitter
</a>
```

**Client Controller**:

Is the following approach correct?

```
$scope.twitter = function() {
  $http.get('oauth/twitter').then(function(res) {
    // Fetch the user from response and store it somewhere on the client side
  });
};
```

The server side responsible for handling authentication looks as follows:

**Server routes**:

```
app.get('/oauth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
  failureRedirect: '/signin'
}));

app.get('/oauth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
  failureRedirect: '/signin',
  successRedirect: '/'
}));
```

**Twitter strategy**:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: config.twitter.clientID,
  consumerSecret: config.twitter.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.twitter.callbackURL,
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  var providerData = profile._json;
  providerData.token = token;
  providerData.tokenSecret = tokenSecret;

  var providerUserProfile = {
    fullName: profile.displayName,
    username: profile.username,
    provider: 'twitter',
    providerId: profile.id,
    providerData: providerData
  };

  users.saveOAuthUserProfile(req, providerUserProfile, done);
}));
```

**Users Server Controller**:

```
exports.saveOAuthUserProfile = function (req, profile, done) {
  User.findOne({
    provider: profile.provider,
    providerId: profile.providerId
  }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    } else {
      if (!user) {
        var possibleUsername = profile.username || ((profile.email) ? profile.email.split('@')[0] : '');

        User.findUniqueUsername(possibleUsername, null, function (availableUsername) {
          profile.username = availableUsername;
          user = new User(profile);
          user.fullName = profile.fullName;

          user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
              var message = getErrorMessage(err);
              req.flash('error', message);
              return done(err);
            }

            return done(err, user);
          });
        });
      } else {
        return done(err, user);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

When I click `Sign in with Twitter` in a browser (Chrome/Firefox) I see the following requests being made:

1. GET http://localhost:3000/oauth/twitter (302 Moved Temporarily)
2. GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=Zz014AAAAAAAg5HgAA******** (307 Internal Redirect)

The browser complains about missing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers.

To fix this I have tried using `cors` package like this

```
var cors = require('cors');
api.use(cors());
```

and also manually setting headers of all responses, with no effect.

Could you please show me the way?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cors module,try to set header in nodejs

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: No effect. AFAIR this middleware cannot affect the response coming from different host (in this case `api.twitter.com`)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with a similar problem and couldn't fix it within the code. So I found this Chrome extension: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

You can set URL patterns and enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Don't forget to disable it when you finish your work!